# Bluetooth is disabled and cannot be enable in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth is not working. I kept on clicking the enable switch for bluetooth, but it still doesn't work. There is also no icon in the menu bar.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep blue; rfkill list all; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, here is the result of

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net;
lsusb;
lsmod | grep blue;
rfkill list all;
dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm' ;

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [144d:c0d8]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [144d:4105]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2232:1029 Silicon Motion WebCam SC-13HDL11939N
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             520192  11 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[    3.433387] [Firmware Bug]: battery: (dis)charge rate invalid.
[    4.428395] usb 1-1.2: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   21.980276] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   21.980289] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.980291] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.980293] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.980297] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.313988] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   27.318026] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1009 tx timeout
[   45.819681] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   45.819684] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   45.819688] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```